# FileMaker 14 Runtime / High Sierra / Download versus copy from Server

Tags: runtime, macos-sierra, filemaker, macos-high-sierra

I have asked this earlier, but the question got downwoted and deleted by any reason. The original is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749448/filemaker-14-runtime-high-sierra-download-versus-copy-from-server

I am posting it again since I now have found the solution that is highly relevant for others having the same issue.

#### Original question:FileMaker 14 Runtime / High Sierra / Download versus copy from Server

Our solution consisting of a couple of FileMaker files built with runtime option. FileMaker14

When packed as a ZIP archive, or a DMG package - The result depends on how the package is downloaded.

Option 1: Distributed as a download link. When unpacking, the application does not work as expected. FileMaker ask for missing files in solution.

Option 2: Same file put on a FTP area, and connected as a remote disk. Then dragged into the the computer. Unpacking, all works well.

Does anyone have a clue what is going on here ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found what is causing this.

Apple has introduced something called "Gateway Path Randomization". This is basically that the App-file is moved by the gatekeeper to a random location prohibiting it from accessing the database files (That is relative to the app itself). This occurs when an app is downloaded from the internet, and not have any certs. To Solve this, You need to sign the DMG archive with a propper certificate. I used DropDMG to accomplish this, then the translocation process does not occur when user is launching the app.

References:

https://community.filemaker.com/thread/165583

https://mjtsai.com/blog/2016/06/16/gatekeeper-path-randomization/